# Is this javascript syntactically correct or is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically if a variable isn't set then set it to another value.

There must be a better way, this looks so messy.

```
        if ($image_src === undefined) {
                $image_src = $apple_icon;
            }

            if ($image_src === undefined) {
                $image_src = $apple_icon2;
            }

            if ($image_src === undefined) {
                $image_src = $item_prop_image;
            }

            if ($image_src === undefined) {
                $image_src = $image_first;
            }
```

Comment: It is syntactically correct, though i question the logic behind it.

Comment: This does seem kind of messy. Some times, when confronted with something that requires you to write "ugly" code (no offence ;), you should take a step back and look at your application's flow. Perhaps you need to alter the logic slightly to make your code more maintainable (and readable)

Comment: @chris Is there a possibility that the `$apple_icon` variable itself (or any of the rest) is not defined? If so, then your script will actually blow up, not just return undefined. You'd need to check with something like `if typeof($apple_icon !== "undefined")`

Comment: @JoeEnos No, I don't think so.. I think he has that many `if` just because `$apple_icon` may be undefined.

Comment: @KevinB: Questioning the logic behind things is a path to the Dark Side

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In JavaScript you can use the or `||` operator to condense things that are undefined.  So this is valid:

```
$image_src = $image_src || $apple_icon || $apple_icon1;
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The first value that is defined is used.

Comment: This looks like a handy thing to have in a JavaScript toolbox :P Thanks guys! Although I think [kevin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279162/is-this-javascript-syntatically-correct-or-is-there-a-better-way#comment18102819_13279162) makes a good point in the comments.

Comment: @gddc—strictly, the first identifier whose value resolves to true is used, or the last one regardless of whether it resolves to true or false. If the identifiers aren't defined at all, an error will be thrown. And if the value is `undefined`, `null`, `0`, etc. then it will be defined and resolve to false.

Answer (score 4):

```
$image_src = $image_src || $apple_icon;
```

http://billhiggins.us/blog/2007/02/13/the-javascript-logical-or-assignment-idiom/

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment - just in case you do have the scenario where one of the variables may not have been declared, you can do something like the following - harder to read, but safer:

```
$image_src = getWhateverTheInitialValueIsSupposedToBe();

$image_src = $image_src || (
    (typeof($apple_icon) !== "undefined" && $apple_icon) ? $apple_icon :
    (typeof($apple_icon2) !== "undefined" && $apple_icon2) ? $apple_icon2 :
    (typeof($item_prop_image) !== "undefined" && $item_prop_image) ? $item_prop_image :
    (typeof($image_first) !== "undefined" && $image_first) ? $image_first :
    $image_src);
```

Comment: +1, however there is no need for grouping the argument for `typeof`. It's an operator, not a function (e.g. `typeof $apple_icon == 'undefined'`).

Comment: @RobG You're right. Actually I think I usually do leave out the parens - don't know why I put them in this time.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think the way you've written it shows clearly what you want to do.

You can make it more compact through the ways shown in the other answers, but I find the way you wrote it is more readily understandable at first glance than the others IMO.

It all depends on what you want.  The `||` method is probably more efficient, but yours is quite readable.

Wrapping this in a function would be fine.